# sharepoint 2010 get ACL for a file using an API

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, shared-libraries, acl

is there a way to get the ACL for a particular file in sharepoint 2010 either by passing filename along with list name or fileId to any of the API's.
If yes please specify the API and parameters to be passed to that API